# Adding cells and scrolling in UITableView causes weird behavior

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to add a pull to add cell functionality to my tableview and am having trouble properly displaying my data. Currently the way it works is that when the user begins pulling down, a placeholder cell is placed as a subview until the user either lets go or pulls down far enough. Once the user pulls down far enough, a new ToDoItem is added to an array of ToDo items, which the tableview is built off of, and then the data reloaded to show the new item and the placeholder cell is removed. It works fine until I begin to delete and check off cells. Once I do so, some cells appear to be checked off despite not checking them off and others disappear until I tap on them.

[The behavior can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIxIX.gif)

All of these functions are in my TableViewController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TodoTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let item = todoList[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.textField.text = item.text
    cell.selectionStyle = .none        
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.toDoItem = item

    // make seperators go edge to edge
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero

    return cell
}

// delete task from list
func deleteItem(_ item: ToDoItem) {
    let index = todoList.index(of: item)
    if  index == nil {
        return
    }
    todoList.remove(at: index!)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

var count = 0

func addItem() {
    count += 1
    let toDoItem = ToDoItem(text: "New cell " + String(count))
    todoList.insert(toDoItem, at: 0)
    tableView.reloadData()
    //tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .none)
}

let placeHolderCell = TodoTableViewCell()
var pullDown = false

override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    pullDown = scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0.0
    if pullDown {
        placeHolderCell.backgroundColor = settings.backgroundColor
        placeHolderCell.textField.text = "Pull down to add"
        tableView.insertSubview(placeHolderCell, at: 0)
    }
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 && pullDown {
        placeHolderCell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -tableView.rowHeight, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.rowHeight)
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -tableView.rowHeight && pullDown {
            scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
    }
    else {
        placeHolderCell.removeFromSuperview()
        pullDown = false
    }

}

override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if !scrollView.isScrollEnabled {
        addItem()
        placeHolderCell.removeFromSuperview()
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
    pullDown = false
}
```

Comment: why `cell.delegate = self` here?

Comment: The delete method in my controller is accessed by my custom TableViewCell. I have the pan left and right handled in the custom cell class so when the user pans left enough, the cell calls the delete method in the controller.